HLA programming
Write an HLA Assembly language program that implements the following function:
procedure multiplesOfAnother( i: int32; j : int32 ); @nodisplay; @noframe;
This function should return into EAX the value 1 if the parameters are multiples of one another; otherwise, return into EAX the value 0.  In order to receive full credit, you should be preventing register corruption by preserving and then restoring the value of any register your function touches.  This rule applies to every register except for EAX which is being used to pass an answer back to the calling code.
Feed Me i: 10
Feed Me j: 20
EAX = 1
Feed Me i: 7
Feed Me j: 30
EAX = 0
Feed Me i: 20
Feed Me j: 10
EAX = 1
Hint: Since we haven't learned how to do much math (coming soon...), I am assuming you will keep adding the smaller value to itself over and over again until you reach the bigger amount.  If after a bunch of additions, your smaller value gets bigger than the bigger amount, you know it wasn't a multiple of the earlier value.
I wrote this code but I keep getting output 0 no matter what and I have no idea where should I fix.
    program multiples;
    #include("stdlib.hhf");

    static
    Value1 : int32 :=0;
    Value2 : int32 :=0;

    procedure multiplesOfAnother(i: int32; j: int32 ); @nodisplay; @noframe;
    static
    returnAddress : dword;
    temp: int32;

    begin multiplesOfAnother;

    pop( returnAddress );
    pop( temp );
    pop( i );
    pop( j );
    push( returnAddress );

    //initial check if the values are zero or negative
    cmp( i, 1 );
    jl NotMultiple;
    cmp( j, 1 );
    jl NotMultiple;
    
    mov( i, ebx );
    mov( j, ecx );

    //determine which i and j is bigger
    cmp( ebx, ecx );
    jg Smallerj;        //if i is greater than j jump to samlleri loop
    jl Smalleri;        //if i is smaller than j jump to smallerj loop
    je YesMultiples;    //if i is equal to j jump to equal loop

    Smalleri:
    mov( i, edx );      //set i to the edx register
    add( i, edx );      //add i
    cmp( j, edx );      //compare with j
    jg NotMultiple;     //if j is greater than multiples of i, exit with EDX=0
    je YesMultiples;    //if j is equal to multiples of i, exit with EDX=1
    jmp Smalleri;       //otherwise, keep adding 

    Smallerj:
    mov( j, edx );      //set j to the edx register
    add( j, edx );      //add j
    cmp( i, edx );      //compare with i
    jg NotMultiple;
    je YesMultiples;
    jmp Smallerj;

    YesMultiples:
    mov( 1, eax );
    jmp EndProcedure;

    NotMultiple:
    mov( 0, eax );
    jmp EndProcedure;

    EndProcedure:
    ret();

    end multiplesOfAnother;

    begin multiples;
    stdout.put( "Feed me i: " );
    stdin.get( Value1 );
    stdout.put( "Feed me j: " );
    stdin.get( Value2 );

    push( Value1 );
    push( Value2 );
    call multiplesOfAnother;

    //Check the result
    cmp( eax, 1 );
    je Yes;
    jmp No;

    Yes:
    stdout.put("EAX =  ");
    stdout.puti32(eax);
    jmp EndProgram;
    No:
    stdout.put("EAX =  ");
    stdout.puti32(eax);
    jmp EndProgram;

    EndProgram:
    stdout.newln();

    end multiples;



Use a debugger. If you don't have a debugger, take pen and paper and manually single-step through the code. It shouldn't be hard to see why the program behaves the way it behaves.
